# Adding notifications for review

Tags: feature-request, review

There should be some kind of option that you get notifications when there are posts to be reviewed.This could speed up the process for reviewing and maybe even attract other people to review posts.

Comment: This thing exists, you're just 7,932 points shy from seeing it.

Comment: My apology,didn't know such thing existed.Never thought such option would be gained at 10k